# How to get distinct values using LISTAGG and Regexp_replace

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Below is my query :

```
SELECT LISTAGG(product_name, chr(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_name) "Product_Listing"
FROM products;
```

Output of query is:

```
apple
orange
apple
mango
orange
banana
banana
apple
```

Required output is:

```
apple
orange
mango
banana
```

How can I use regexp_replace for this? Any other functions/idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the input data. It is pretty hard to give the answer you require without it.

Answer (score 5):

It is achievable without `REGEXP_REPLACE` for example using`DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(product_name, chr(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_name) 
       "Product_Listing" 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT product_name FROM products) s;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9e387ddabb1bd1ab7d3b18610f75994a)**

Comment: I have other columns also on which I am using LISTAGG. Thats why I want to select distinct values after LISTAGG. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @user10273980 a inaccurate question will generate a inaccurate answer.. Nothing in the question indicate the use off multiple columns.. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "**Help others reproduce the problem**" or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: "Thats why I want to select distinct values after LISTAGG. How can I achieve this?" That's not eazy then you need to dynamically convert the LISTAGG string back to records you don't want to go that way.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking for one row with the distinct products, then Lukasz's method works fine.

If you actually want any other summary columns, then it probably won't do what you want.  You can use this instead:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN product_name END, chr(10))
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_name) as Product_Listing
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_name ORDER BY product_name) as seqnum
      FROM products p
     ) p;
```

I do not advise removing the duplicates *after* the `LISTAGG()`, if only because Oracle imposes a pretty short limit on the result.  But you can do it as:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(LISTAGG(product_name END, chr(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY product_name),
                      '([^\x10]+)(\x10\1)+',
                      '\1'
                     ) as Product_Listing
FROM products p;
```

This removes adjacent duplicates.  Because of the `ORDER BY`, the duplicates are adjacent.  So, it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I want to achieve this using regexp_replace after LISTAGG. Is this possible?

Comment: @user10273980 . . . Why?  This is a simple enough solution.

Comment: I have below situation:

Comment: SELECT ID, CL_T, PG , 

                      LISTAGG(name, chr(10)) within group (order by name) as NAME,

                      LISTAGG(job, chr(10)) within group (order by job) as JOB,

                      LISTAGG(Salary, chr(10)) within group (order by salary) as salary

                      from EMP

                      GROUP BY ID, CL_T, PG HAVING CL_t = 'COMMT' ORDER BY ID;

Comment: I want Name column with distinct value and JOB AND SALARY columns with LISTAGG OUTPUT.

Comment: @user10273980 . . . You have two valid answers to the question you asked (and you should accept one of them).  You seem to have a more detailed question.  Ask *another* question, provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want.  Don't edit this question, because it will invalidate answers and that can attract downvotes.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I tried with the REGEXP_REPLACE query that you provided. But its not working for me as my values are on different lines after LISTAGG. Please see the query output and required output on my question above.

Comment: @user10273980 . . . You need to use the linefeed character rather than a comma.